# How to redirect non-existent action in CFWheels?

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

I have a basic app going and I want users to be redirected to the main base action if an action they try to reach is not in the controller.

I have some routes set up:

```
addRoute(name="pinShow",        pattern="pin/show/[key]",       controller="pin",       action="show");
addRoute(name="pinShow",        pattern="pin/show",             controller="pin",       action="show");
addRoute(name="pin",            pattern="pin",                  controller="pin",       action="index");
```

At the moment, if the user types `/pin/something/` in the URL, the action loaded is index, but is stays on this URL. I want to do a 301 redirect and not simply load in the default action view, etc.

I thought I'd be able to do this with the verifies function in my controller, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
verifies( except="index,show", handler="invalidAction" );
```

With my handler being:

```
private void function invalidAction() {

    flashInsert( messages = [{ messageString="Invalid action.", messageType="info" }] );
    redirectTo(route="pin");

}
```

None of this is working. Any idea's anyone?

I'm about to go live and it's just something I want to tighten up! I'd rather kill a link with a 404 or redirect rather than have the default action loaded in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your routes to look like this:

```
addRoute(name="pinShow", pattern="pin/show/[key]", controller="pin", action="show");
addRoute(name="pinShow", pattern="pin/show",       controller="pin", action="show");
addRoute(name="pin",     pattern="pin/[invalid]",  controller="pin", action="invalidAction");
addRoute(name="pin",     pattern="pin",            controller="pin", action="index");
```

In this case, you may need to make the `invalidAction` method `public` for this to work.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Still getting to grips with the power of routes.

Answer (score 1):

@Michael Giovanni Pumo  you can use onmissingtemplate event of wheels and there you can write a function to redirect to home page